# Bounty option not shown

Tags: support, bounty

I don't see the bounty option under [the question I asked](https://superuser.com/questions/1028987/word-how-to-make-a-header1-after-a-textfield).

No one has answered yet and I thought if I make a bounty and offered 50 points, people might help more.

Comment: Before you place a bounty, be sure you answer the questions in the comments, otherwise you will just place a bounty on an unanswerable question

Comment: @Ramhound there is no comments

Comment: DavidPostill submitted one 3 hours ago.  Go look again

Answer (score 3):

There's a few reasons - They're [listed here](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) but two of them specifically would be of interest.

- The question is too new `The question has been asked in the last 48 hours. Give the community a chance to answer your question normally first.`
- You need a minimum of *75* reputation to set a bounty - at the time of asking you have 61. Even then, this is a *significant* part of your bounty.

Comment: Okay thank you, i will wait to get the 75 point

Comment: Ok, but what if a question is new, already has 3 answers and I agree with none of them? I would like to add a bounty for authorative reference. If I need to wait for another day, I'll just forget that I wanted to do this

Answer (score 2):

#### I don't see the option to start a bounty?

From [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://superuser.com/help/bounty):

> **How do I start a bounty? When can I start a bounty?**
>
> A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was
>   asked.

Your question is only one day old. You need to wait another day before you can offer a bounty.

In addition, [offering a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) is a [privilege](https://superuser.com/help/privileges) awarded when you have a reputation of 75 points. Your current reputation (61) means you haven't yet earned that privilege.

Comment: my question is two days, so I have to wait until i get 75 point :(. thank you